# Java OAuth Provider Library help

Tags: java, api, rest, oauth

I have a website with a Java back-end and I am in the process of adding a RESTful API which uses OAuth.

I've already got a fairly good idea how to handle the REST part ([Oracle Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html)). But are there any Java libraries to help implement the OAuth part of the problem?

The only one I've found is [this one](http://developers.sun.com/identity/reference/techart/restwebservices.html) But it OpenSSO is no longer free and it doesn't seem to be maintained.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to use Spring? Spring Security now has an OAuth extension, which has done the job for me. In terms of testing the functionality once you've written it, you might want to check out JMeter and it's OAuth plugin.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/index.html

I'd post the links to JMeter, but Stack Overflow won't let me. Google will do just fine though!

Comment: I think I may end up using Spring. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jersey, which supports OAuth 1.0, see http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/OAuth

Comment: Is that still being updated? It only supports OAuth 1.0, not 1.0a.